Creating year buckets from given start and end dates
I have a table with several columns, two of those are dates (year-month-day)(start-end).
Example Table:
|ID|    Start_Date| End-Date|
|-|-|-|
|A| 4/24/2024|  6/2/2025|
|B| 4/24/2024|  7/1/2024|
|C| 4/24/2024|  6/2/2028|
|D| 4/9/2024|   8/2/2028|
I need to create year bucket columns. Grab the year from start date and the year from end date and do a counting. If the year dates are the same then the bucket column would have only 1 year.
Here is my desired output:
|ID|    Start_Date| End-Date|   2024|   2024-2025|  2024-2028|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|A| 4/24/2024|  6/2/2025|   0|  1|  0|
|B| 4/24/2024|  7/1/2024|   1|  0|  0|
|C| 4/24/2024|  6/2/2028|   0|  0|  1|
|D| 4/9/2024|   8/2/2028|   0|  0|  1|
Thank you

count(case when datediff(year, start_date, end_date) = 0 then 1 end), count(case when datediff(year, start_date, end_date) = 1 then 1 end), count(case when datediff(year, start_date, end_date) > 1 then 1 end) This won't handle dynamic naming of the output columns though.

@shawnt00 - typo :  = 0, and third should be case , not cast

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/s-6AKYPF

Please provide a [mre] including sample data, desired results and your attempt - all as formatted text i.e. no images

Btw are you familiar with accepting an answer? You don't appear to have done so on your past questions

Dynamic PIVOT
SELECT ID, 
  start_date, [end-date], 1 as value,
  CASE 
  WHEN year(start_date) = year([end-date]) THEN cast(year(start_date) as varchar(4)) 
  ELSE cast(year(start_date) as varchar(4))  + '-' + CAST(year([end-date]) as VARCHAR(4)) 
  END as Bucket
INTO #bucket  
FROM example;

SELECT * FROM #bucket;

SELECT * FROM
(  
 SELECT ID, value, Start_Date, [End-Date], Bucket FROM #bucket
) results
PIVOT (
  COUNT(value)
  FOR [Bucket] IN ([2024], [2024-2025], [2024-2028])   
) as PivotTable


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.bucket) 
            FROM #bucket c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT   @cols;
    
set @query = 
'SELECT ID, Start_Date, [End-Date], ' + @cols + ' from 
(
 SELECT ID, value, Start_Date, [End-Date], Bucket FROM #bucket
) x
pivot 
(
 COUNT(value)
for Bucket in (' + @cols + ')
) p '

SELECT  @query;   
execute(@query)

fiddle



ID
Start_Date
End-Date
2024
2024-2025
2024-2028




A
4/24/2024
6/2/2025
0
1
0


B
4/24/2024
7/1/2024
1
0
0


C
4/24/2024
6/2/2028
0
0
1


D
4/9/2024
8/2/2028
0
0
1




Thank you so much for your collaboration! Had to do some adjustments since my end date is coming from case when. This is very helpful
